# jquery selector mixup on $(this).find(':nth-child(2)')

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm a bit confused regarding jquery and selectors.

on this site http://pelloponisos.telesto.gr/ i'm building a main menu.
All I want is to make the immediate sub-menu(2nd child of every li in the main menu) appear on mouseover and hide on mouseout.

the jquery code to make the menu work on mouseover is:

```
$("#access ul li").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find(':nth-child(2)').show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(':nth-child(2)',this).hide();
    });
```

but as you can see the code matchess every second child and thus expands the all the submenus at once.

Can somebody please point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using direct child selector:

```
$(this).find('> :nth-child(2)').show();
```

or:

```
$("#access ul li").hover(function(){
    $('> :nth-child(2)', this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Note, this use of the `>` selector is being depreciated in a future release of jQuery. Directly from docs: "Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors." http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ Unless this only specifically applies to it having a context i guess,

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
$(this).children(":eq(1)").show()
```